# Input redirection and rewinding

Tags: c

I am redirecting a text file into my C program, e.g.

```
./test.c < earthquakes.txt
```

and I read in the data I need with a scanf like so:

```
while (scanf("%4d-%2d-%2d%c%2d:%2d:%2d+%2d:%2d,%f,%f,%f,%f",
    &yyyy, &mm, &dd, &junkc, &hh, &min, &sec, &junki, &junki,
    &latit, &longi, &depth, &magnitude) == 13) {
    printf("test\n");
    num_earthquakes++;
}
```

until I've read all the lines I need. After doing that, how do I rewind back to the start of the stdin?

Comment: You usually cannot rewind the *stdin* ; you want to use the [rewind() function](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/C_Reference/stdio.h/rewind) from `<stdio.h>` but you should not expect it to always work on `stdin`; on some systems it might work, but on most systems it would fail. You may prefer to use `fseek` because it reports better failures.

Comment: instead redirection `<` at command prompt. I would suggest user `fscanf()` to read from file. `rewind()` and `fseek()` are two functions that can be use to shift back file pointer to start.

Comment: Ok so there is 100% no way for me to do what I'm looking for right? Just making sure. This is an assignment and we *have* to use input redirection, no file pointers involved. I will likely have to do with just reading through once.

Comment: Please describe your actual problem, problem X, rather than problem Y because you think you need it to solve X.

Comment: @modifiablelvalue That sounds like a good idea. The problem is I want to know how many lines (call it N) there are in the input text file so I can malloc an array of structs (length N), then rewind the stdin so I can populate the array.

Comment: Why do you want to allocate such a potentially large array? That sounds like a horribly inefficient (and error-proned) way to do whatever it is you want to do... Which is what, by the way?

Comment: @modifiablelvalue Haha oh god. What I want to do is read in a list of earthquakes. Each line corresponds to one earthquake - time, latitude/longitude, magnitude, etc. I store an array so I can loop through it once to calculate an overall average of some values, then I loop over it a second time to calculate averages by months. The monthly output *has* to come after the overall output, so I can't just do the monthly output as I go whilst also maintaining a running calculation on the overall averages

Comment: Dynamic arrays are the answer here. But if there was any possibility of large input it would be best to build a dynamic array of the *monthly averages* rather than caching the whole file. "Dynamic array" means (at it's simplest) `malloc`ing a small array and then `realloc`ing it bigger by some factor (typically 1.4 to 2.0) when it needs to be bigger.

Comment: @dmckee Ok thanks. I was hoping there would be a much simpler way of doing it. But unfortunately not :- )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps making one pass is the best option: Read the values, and resize the array using `realloc` when necessary. To minimise the chance of error from huge amounts of input, you'll want to store only the required information to solve your problem. If the output is based on months, then collect information based on months. For example:

```
size_t count = 0;
struct month_stat *month = NULL;
while (count <= SIZE_MAX / sizeof *month &&
       scanf("%4d-%2d-%2d%c%2d:%2d:%2d+%2d:%2d,%f,%f,%f,%f",
             &yyyy, &mm, &dd, &junkc, &hh, &min, &sec, &junki, &junki,
             &latit, &longi, &depth, &magnitude) == 13)
{
    /* resize based upon powers of two for simplicity */
    if (count & (count - 1) == 0)
    {
        void *temp = realloc(month, (count * 2 + 1) * sizeof *month);
        if (temp == NULL)
        {
            /* handle error */
        }

        month = temp;
    }

    /* TODO: Update month[count] and overall stats
     *       When the month changes, you'll want to count++;
     */
}
```

Are you aware that you can tell scanf to discard input by placing a `*` between the `%` and whichever format specifier you use? For example, `assert(scanf("%*c") == 0);` would read and discard a character without assignment, which reflects upon the return value.

Comment: Thanks I was hoping there was an easier version but I have gone with realloc. Also I did not know that about being able to do that with scanf - thankyou for the useful tip. That scanf line was provided to us but I have used your suggestion anyway ^^

Answer (score 2):

`stdin` is a stream and not a regular file, so you can't just rewind the input.

So I suppose, you should use a regular reading from the file, or if you want to copy received data to the buffer, in order to read it again.

Comment: What do you mean - copy received data to the buffer? What is "the buffer"?

Comment: @nebffa I mean a temporary array. But it is not good in general. I think, the best in your case is using file.

Answer (score 0):

A possible way is to built, during the first lecture, a representation in memory. For instance, you create a linked list corresponding to each line, and the element are your own struct.

That way, to read once and after, you have an interesting and convinient way to use them.